# How to uninstall GVM

Tags: grails, groovy, gvm

I use GVM to manage my Groovy/Grails environment.

How do I uninstall GVM and all the candidates currently installed?

I suspect one would simply just delete the `~/.gvm` directory. Surprisingly the [GVM website](http://gvmtool.net/) doesn't seem to mention how to do this, nor is there documentation to confirm how this is done.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Deleting the `~/.gvm` directory and removing the lines:

```
#THIS MUST BE AT THE END OF THE FILE FOR GVM TO WORK!!!
[[ -s "~/.gvm/bin/gvm-init.sh" && ! $(which gvm-init.sh) ]] && source "~/.gvm/bin/gvm-init.sh"
```

From `~/.bash_profile` (or `~/.profile`), `~/.bashrc` and `~/.zshrc` should do it (assuming a default install)

Comment: Will this also delete any jars/libraries that were downloaded for previously developed grails projects? I'm curious as to where grails installs its dependencies.

Comment: No, they will be in the `~/.grails` folder as normal.  And Groovy Grapes are in `~/.groovy/grapes`

Answer (score 5):

- Un-install Groovy/Grail:
  gvm uninstall groovy/grail version
- Delete /.gvm directory and line in .profile or .bash (as steps above)
- Delete ~/.groovy directory  (this is groovy log location)

That will clean up gvm and its environment.

Comment: Thats the better answer. See gvm help for all available commands.

Comment: That won't remove the directories from the PATH environment variable. The answer by @tim_yates mentions that too.